# Elastic Search - Nested matching on array with range

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having issues with my search results.

I have the following mapping on my index:

```html
{
  "index": {
    "mappings": {
      "shop": {
        "properties": {
          "about": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "address": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "operationHours": {
            "type": "nested",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "properties": {
              "dayOfWeek": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "timeRanges": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_parent": true,
                "properties": {
                  "from": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "to": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "phone": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "profileImageName": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then added the following document:

```html
{
    "operationHours": [
      {
        "timeRanges": [
          {
            "to": 720,
            "from": 600
          },
          {
            "to": 1500,
            "from": 840
          }
        ],
        "dayOfWeek": 0
      },
      {
        "timeRanges": [
          {
            "to": 720,
            "from": 700
          },
          {
            "to": 960,
            "from": 840
          }
        ],
        "dayOfWeek": 2
      },
      {
        "timeRanges": [
          {
            "to": 720,
            "from": 600
          },
          {
            "to": 1500,
            "from": 840
          }
        ],
        "dayOfWeek": 4
      },
      {
        "timeRanges": [
          {
            "to": 720,
            "from": 600
          },
          {
            "to": 1500,
            "from": 840
          }
        ],
        "dayOfWeek": 5
      },
      {
        "timeRanges": [
          {
            "to": 720,
            "from": 600
          },
          {
            "to": 1500,
            "from": 840
          }
        ],
        "dayOfWeek": 6
      },
      {
        "timeRanges": [
          {
            "to": 720,
            "from": 600
          },
          {
            "to": 1500,
            "from": 840
          }
        ],
        "dayOfWeek": 7
      }
    ],
    "location": {
      "lon": "-68.72307",
      "lat": "25.463178"
    },
    "profileImageName": "ACRUEX.jpg",
    "address": "620 Classon Avenue, Hendersonville, Mississippi, 4076",
    "description": "Tempor culpa dolore Lorem fugiat dolore esse. Ullamco ipsum dolore amet dolor laboris eu nisi consequat Lorem non mollit minim exercitation. Voluptate ipsum mollit culpa aute sunt consectetur minim anim cupidatat dolor quis labore do amet. Non id voluptate dolore nostrud laboris voluptate consequat aliqua labore.",
    "about": "Non labore culpa do consectetur fugiat velit. Reprehenderit cupidatat nulla veniam exercitation adipisicing amet. Mollit irure voluptate dolor est veniam nulla fugiat elit. Non et deserunt excepteur non officia enim non voluptate qui amet adipisicing quis enim exercitation.",
    "email": "undefined.undefined@undefined.io",
    "phone": "+1 (833) 575-2171",
    "name": "ISOPOP"
}
```

I then use the following query to get documents that have operating hour ranges that are greater than or equal to a specified time (730 in the example).

The 730 represents the minutes from midnight i.e. 730 is 12:10pm.

```html
GET index/shop/1/_explain
{   
   "query": { 
     "nested" : {
       "path" : "operationHours",
       "query": {
         "bool" : {
           "must" : [
             { "match" : { "operationHours.dayOfWeek" : 2 } },
             { "range": {"operationHours.timeRanges.from": { "lte": 730 }}},
             { "range": {"operationHours.timeRanges.to": { "gt": 730 }}}
                ]
             
         }
         
       }
     }
   }
}
```

It comes up as a match and it shouldnt do as the value of '730' doesnt fall within the ranges of 700 to 720 and 840 to 960.

Any help as to where Im going wrong would be great.

Comment: what are you trying to say , can you please recheck your values in your query.

Comment: What Im trying to say, is I want documents returned that have to and from ranges that cover a int value I pass. For example, the document above has to and from values 700 and 720 for dayOfWeek=2. If I pass 710, the document must be returned. If I pass 730, the document must not be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The following does exactly what I need it to do

```
{
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "operationHours",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "operationHours.dayOfWeek": 2
                    }
                }, {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "operationHours.timeRanges",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [{
                                        "range": {
                                            "operationHours.timeRanges.to": {
                                                "gt": 600
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        "range": {
                                            "operationHours.timeRanges.from": {
                                                "lte": 600
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

"It comes up as a match and it shouldnt do as the value of '730' doesnt fall within the ranges of 700 to 720 and 840 to 960."

This is the proper query to check if the document matches for operational hours for the given ranges 700 to 720 and 840 to 960. (i am considering OR between them) and your document will not match this query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "operationHours",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "operationHours.dayOfWeek": 2
                        }
                    }, {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [{
                                    "range": {
                                        "operationHours.timeRanges.from": {
                                            "lt": 720,
                                            "gt": 700
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "range": {
                                        "operationHours.timeRanges.from": {
                                            "lt": 840,
                                            "gt": 960
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            ],
                            "minimum_number_should_match": 1
                        }
                    }]

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can adjust `gt to gte` according to your usecase.

Comment: The problem with that is that I wont know the lt/gt ranges. All I have is the 730 time stamp, so I need to know if 730 falls between the to/from values.